# Timeline (year and event)

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

Here is the desired output, the errors, and the output I get:

[image: error&output]

Here is the code I tried:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.geometric
  ,positioning
}
\tikzset{
  zeitmarkernode/.style={
    isosceles triangle
    ,minimum height=2.5mm
    ,inner sep=0pt
    ,anchor=apex
  },
  zeitmarker/.pic={%
    \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=-90](-o){};
    \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=90](-u){};
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6cm,thick]
% Achse und Beschriftung unterhalb
  \draw(2000)coordinate(s)--(2018)coordinate()--(2027)coordinate(e)--(2050)coordinate(e);
  \foreach \c/\zeit in {s/2000,2018,2027,2050}
    \draw(\c)node[below=.5cm of \c]{\zeit}--+(0,.1)--+(0,-.1);
% Markierungen, Beschriftungen oberhalb und Verbindungen
  \foreach[count=\i] \h/\min/\sec/\hshift in {%
     approach 1-5mm,%
     approach 2-1cm,%
      approach 3-1cm%
      approach 4-1cm%
    }{
    \pic[fill=blue](zm\i) at ({\h+\min/60+\sec/3600},0){zeitmarker};
      \node[above=1cm of zm\i-o,xshift=\hshift](zm\i){\h:\min:\sec};
      \coordinate(h) at ([yshift=5mm]zm\i-o);
      \draw[blue](h)edge(zm\i)edge(zm\i-o);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is [the original code from www.texwelt.de](http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/12880/zeitachse-timeline):

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  shapes.geometric
  ,positioning
}
\tikzset{
  zeitmarkernode/.style={
    isosceles triangle
    ,minimum height=2.5mm
    ,inner sep=0pt
    ,anchor=apex
  },
  zeitmarker/.pic={%
    \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=-90](-o){};
    \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=90](-u){};
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=6cm,thick]
% Achse und Beschriftung unterhalb
  \draw(12,0)coordinate(s)--(14,0)coordinate(e);
  \foreach \c/\zeit in {s/12:00,e/14:00}
    \draw(\c)node[below=.5cm of \c]{\zeit}--+(0,.1)--+(0,-.1);
% Markierungen, Beschriftungen oberhalb und Verbindungen
  \foreach[count=\i] \h/\min/\sec/\hshift in {%
      12/00/00/-5mm,%
      12/30/00/1cm,%
      14/00/00/-1cm%
    }{
      \pic[fill=blue](zm\i) at ({\h+\min/60+\sec/3600},0){zeitmarker};
      \node[above=1cm of zm\i-o,xshift=\hshift](zm\i){\h:\min:\sec};
      \coordinate(h) at ([yshift=5mm]zm\i-o);
      \draw[blue](h)edge(zm\i)edge(zm\i-o);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: http://www.texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/12880/zeitachse-timeline here is the code that I have copied it. I have changed nothing  but unfortunately I did not know how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than posting links, which may not be available in the future, please make your question self-contained by including a [minimal non-working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) in the body of the question (not as a comment!) that demonstrates your problem.  Secondly, please post the error message that you are getting on overleaf. It seems likely, in this case, that the code is valid and that it is instead a problem with how you are using overleaf. The chance of some one being able to guess what your problem is without more details is quite small.

Comment: Your code works both on Overleaf and on local for me. Which error does it give to you? Have you tried to update your TeX distribution?

Comment: Andrew thank you for feedback it s ok :)  @CarLaTex to be honset I  did not understand the code well( am pretty new on latex) , once I have tried it and I have changed 12:00:00 by approach 1 for example and 12by 2000 etc etc it gives me a lot of error I have added a screenshot for it, and the output I got... I did not know how to fix it ( I have added the code i tried + errors because as you can see the privious code does not give the desired figure I have do it on paint etc etc

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

The `\foreach` command, when the variable of the loop is only one, has this syntax:

```
\foreach <variable> in 
     {<variable_value_1>,<variable_value_2>,...,<variable_value_n>}
     {code}
```

when the variables of the loop are more than one, they (and their values) are separated by `/`:

```
\foreach <variable_1/variable_2/.../variable_m> in 
     {<variable_1_value_1/variable_2_value_1/.../variable_m_value_1>,
      <variable_1_value_2/variable_2_value_2/.../variable_m_value_2>,
       ...,
      <variable_1_value_n/variable_2_value_n/.../variable_m_value_n>}
     {code}
```

you have changed the number of variables in the list of the values without changing the list of variables.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric
    ,positioning
}
\tikzset{
    zeitmarkernode/.style={
        isosceles triangle
        ,minimum height=2.5mm
        ,inner sep=0pt
        ,anchor=apex
    },
    zeitmarker/.pic={%
        \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=-90](-o){};
        \node[zeitmarkernode,pic actions,rotate=90](-u){};
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=6cm,thick]
    % Achse und Beschriftung unterhalb
    \draw (11.9,0) -- (12,0) coordinate (s) -- (12+18/25,0) coordinate (a) 
        -- (12+27/25,0) coordinate (b) -- (14,0) coordinate (e) -- (14.2,0);
    \foreach \c/\zeit in {s/2000,a/2018,b/2027,e/2050}
        \draw (\c) node[below=.5cm of \c] {\zeit} -- +(0,.1) -- +(0,-.1);
    % Markierungen, Beschriftungen oberhalb und Verbindungen
    \foreach[count=\i] \descr/\c/\hshift in {%
        approach 1/s/5mm,%
        approach 2/a/5mm,%
        approach 3/b/5mm,%
        approach 4/e/3mm%
    }{
        \pic[fill=blue] (zm\i) at (\c) {zeitmarker};
        \node[above=1cm of zm\i-o,xshift=\hshift] (zm\i) {\emph{\descr}};
        \coordinate(h) at ([yshift=5mm]zm\i-o);
        \draw[blue](h) edge (zm\i) edge (zm\i-o);
    }
    \node[below left =.5cm and 1cm of s, text width=5em, align=center, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex] {\emph{Year}};
    \node[above left =.5cm and 1cm of s, text width=5em, align=center] {\emph{Approaches}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it work thank you very much, it gives me the desired timline as the figure you get.. but on local i get this msg ( "Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: time-line.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file time-line.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file time-line.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file time-line.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s) "am i supposed to do somthing or leave it,since it works fine!(thank you you saved my day thank you)

Comment: @magda Don't run `bibtex` on your `time-line` if it doesn't have a bibliography. Your editor may be unhelpfully running this for you if you are using some kind of combo-compilation which combines `bibtex` with `pdflatex` or whatever.

Comment: thank you CarLaTeX, @cfr  ..." if it doesn't have a bibliography." (sorry because am not very familiar) what do you mean, basically i have made a seperated example but yeah for sure my project has a  bibliography (I have not yet included it I have tried the CarLaTeX s'code( thank you again) seperatly. maybee this way it gives me this msg !!... ' if you are using some kind of combo-compilation which combines bibtex with pdflatex or whatever" I did not understand !!

Comment: @magda If you have a bibliography you'll also have a package like `natbib` or similar. To compile a document with bibliography you have to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and then again `pdflatex` twice. If you have another problem it's better if you ask another question with a example of your code, as indicated here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407.

Comment: @CarLaTeX +1 for you fine and good work.

Comment: @magda The message you posted is from a run of `bibtex`. So something is running `bibtex`. It is unhappy because the code doesn't include code for a bibliography, which `bibtex` expects since that's its purpose in life.

Comment: @cfr it is okey thank you guys :) merci pour vous tous :) (y)